# Can someone help me start an apache airflow?

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to install apache airflow and I get a syntax error. I have python 2.7

Error:

```
$pip install apache-airflow

Collecting apache-airflow
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/_z/q60knmsn7m11y4hf82qbg4p00000gn/T/pip-install-f9ssqcze/apache-airflow/setup.py", line 102
        async = [
              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1...
```

Comment: It might help if you included the error message in your question

Comment: Also your setup - i.e. your OS, the commands you sent and why you need Python 3.

Comment: I need python3 to install apache airflow and I am using a mac

Comment: I think this is a good question and when I ran into the same problem, couldn't have found the solution without this post. However, this was down voted because of the way it was asked. Please separate out what your actual issue is with what you want the solution to be. If you know the solution, in this case, you want to install Python3, then ask that question. Also, a simple Google search can easily help with how to install Python3.

Answer (score 8):

apache-airflow is not supporting Python3.7 (as of 22 August 2018)

**Install airflow in Python 3.6** and it should work.

If you have already installed python3.7, try package managers like conda. You should be fine. Here are some references:

https://www.mail-archive.com/commits@airflow.incubator.apache.org/msg16846.html
https://gitter.im/apache/incubator-airflow?at=5b5130bac86c4f0b47201af0
https://gitter.im/apache/incubator-airflow?at=5b5131149ddf5f4aadf78379